# Creating RAID 1 using mdadm for Root disk in Linux:

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid1, mdraid

I recently found one of our production server (running RHEL7) doesn’t have the root disk mirrored. So, we thought of using one of the spare disks (which has some junk data) for mirroring the root disk using mdraid.

I wanted to do it without disturbing anything on the server as it’s in production. I was checking how to do this with mdraid but couldn’t find anything that’s helpful.

Can someone please let me know how I can mirror the existing root disk with RAID 1 using mdraid?

Thanks in advance.

-Ram

Comment: You can prepare this online, but you need to remount to make it really active. The boot device is already mirrored?

Comment: Even I was reading that it can be done online (using mdraid) but couldn’t find out the steps to do the same. For re-mounting, I can reboot the box once during non-production hours and ~10 mins disruption should be fine.

The boot device isn’t mirrored currently.